# errors/{id} documentation : 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

On [Documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help) page, clicking on

> errors/{id}

returns *500 Internal Server Error*

EDIT:
Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also getting error here, and Rate-Limit counter is decreasing even with that error page.

**Edit**: Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed.